# How to use selector xpath properly in combination with extensions?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://sample.domain.com/the/target/namespace"
           xmlns:tns="http://sample.domain.com/the/target/namespace"
           targetNamespace="http://sample.domain.com/the/target/namespace"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="rootElement" type="rootType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="rootType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="parentElement" type="parentType">
                <xs:unique name="uniqueId">
                    <xs:selector xpath="tns:abstractElement"/> <!-- should access the abstractElement OR all extensions -->
                    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
                </xs:unique>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="parentType">
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="childElementA" type="childTypeA"/>
            <xs:element name="childElementB" type="childTypeB"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="abstractElement" type="abstractType" abstract="true"/> <!-- how to access this element via xpath -->

    <xs:complexType name="abstractType" abstract="true">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="childTypeA">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="abstractType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="childChildA"> <!-- how to access this element via xpath in combination with 'childChildB' -->
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="childTypeB">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="abstractType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="childChildB"> <!-- how to access this element via xpath in combination with 'childChildA' -->
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and a sample instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootElement
    xmlns="http://sample.domain.com/the/target/namespace"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://sample.domain.com/the/target/namespace schema.xsd">

    <parentElement>
        <childElementA id="duplicate">
            <childChildA id="foo"/>
        </childElementA>
        <childElementB id="duplicate">
            <childChildB id="bar"/>
        </childElementB>
    </parentElement>

</rootElement>
```

**First**
I want to validate that the id attributes of the child elements are unique. With `xpath="*"` *it's working* in some cases (see above).
What *does not work* is `xpath="childElementA"` or `xpath="abstractElement"`.

**Second**
How can I access the ids of the extensions' elements `childChildA` and `childChildB` in only one set?

**Additionally**
Is this good or bad practice to use extensions and xpaths together that way?

P.S. The named complexTypes are needed because of JAXB (Java XML Bindings).

**UPDATE 1**
I also tried a selector with the targetNamespace in prefix, like that `xpath="xs:childElementA"` or `xpath="xs:abstractElement"`. But it didn't worked for me too.

**UPDATE 2**
I mapped the targetNamespace to the prefix 'tns'. And I added a sample instance, where the *id* of *childElementA* and *childElementB* are equal. Therefore, it should not validate. But it does:

```
$ xmllint --noout --schema schema.xsd schema-instance.xml
schema-instance.xml validates
```

Comment: Do you have a targetNamespace?

Comment: If you have a `targetNamespace` your XPath selectors need to be qualified by a namespace. That means that you will have to add a namespace declaration mapping it to a prefix (even if you already have  declared your targetNamespace as the default namespace - you can have both). This is necessary because XPath considers any unprefixed element selectors as belonging to *no-namespace*.

Comment: Ah, that was the thing I have forgotten to mention... I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing your types with the `xs` prefix won't work because your types don't belong to the XML Schema Namespace. They belong to your `targetNamespace`.

You need to map a prefix to your *target namespace*. It is currently declared as the *default* (`xmlns`) namespace, which allows you to refer to your locally declared types and element references without having to qualify them. But XPath selectors (in XSD 1.0*) that are not *explicitly* qualified with a prefix will not behave the same way. Unprefixed selectors will always be considered as belonging to *no namespace*.

To register a prefix/namespace mapping usable by XPath, simply add another namespace declaration for your target namespace, associating it with any prefix (`tns`, for example):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="http://sample.domain.com/the/target/namespace"
           xmlns:tns="http://sample.domain.com/the/target/namespace"
           targetNamespace="http://sample.domain.com/the/target/namespace"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"> ...
```

Now you can use that in your XPath selectors, and it will find the elements in your target namespace:

```
<xs:unique name="uniqueId">
    <xs:selector xpath="tns:abstractElement"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
</xs:unique>
```

* In XSD 1.1 you can declare `xpathDefaultNamespace="##targetNamespace"` to allow XPath expressions to consider unprefixed selectors as belonging to the target namespace, but that is not possible in XSD 1.0.

---

*A note about reference use in the schema:*

You need *both* `xmlns` and `xmlns:tns` declarations if you want to continue to use unprefixed element references and types (which is the standard convention). If you don't care about prefixing them as well, you can keep only the prefixed one `xmlns:tns`, but you would have to prefix all references to types and elements, for example in `<xs:element name="parentElement" type="tns:parentType">` or `<xs:element ref="tns:parentElement"/>`. It's a matter of style.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! I added the `xmlns:tns` and adjusted the xpath in the way you recommend. But still it validates on _id_ duplicates in _abstractType_. I'll add more information to the question in the next hours.

Comment: Be sure your XPath expressions are in the correct context, since no errors are issued if the XPath is incorrect. And make sure that your `xsd:unique` constraints are declared in a context where it makes sense.

Comment: I try, but obviously there are still mistakes I made. I updated the question.